# How to count green and red bars number in the last N days?

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=5
indicator('Bar Count', overlay=false, max_bars_back=1000)
green = close > close[1] ? 1 : 0
red = close < close[1] ? -1 : 0
length = input(30, title='Number of bars lookback')
greenbar = math.sum(green, length)
redbar = math.sum(red, length)

var g_count = 0 
var r_count = 0
```

I finished the first part but I believe it will need to add "tostring" part as I need to count again in next day, but I really don't know how to count those number...Please help me to code this pine script. I am new to the pine script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep the red/green status in an array, and then calculate the sum of the elements in that array to get the red/green bar count, like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Count Bar Color", "CBC")

var int     barsBack        = input.int(30, 'Number of bars lookback', 0)

var int[]   greenBars       = array.new_int(barsBack, 0)
var int[]   redBars         = array.new_int(barsBack, 0)
var int     greenBarCount   = 0
var int     redBarCount     = 0

direction = ta.change(close) // red or green ?

if barstate.isconfirmed             // bar is complete
    if direction > 0                // green bar
        array.push(greenBars, 1)    // append 1 to end of array
        array.push(redBars,   0)    // append 0 to end of array
    else if direction < 0           // red bar
        array.push(greenBars, 0)    // append 0 to end of array
        array.push(redBars,   1)    // append 1 to end of array

    if direction != 0               // we've appended an element to the end of the array
        array.shift(greenBars)      // remove 1st element of array to keep size of array constant
        array.shift(redBars)        // remove 1st element of array to keep size of array constant

    greenBarCount := array.sum(greenBars)
    redBarCount   := array.sum(redBars)

plot(greenBarCount, 'greenBarCount', color.green)
plot(redBarCount,   'redBarCount',   color.red)
```

Shorter version:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Count Bar Color", "CBC")

var int     barsBack        = input.int(30, 'Number of bars lookback', 0)

var int[]   greenBars       = array.new_int(barsBack, 0)
var int[]   redBars         = array.new_int(barsBack, 0)
var int     greenBarCount   = 0
var int     redBarCount     = 0

direction = ta.change(close)

if barstate.isconfirmed and direction != 0
    array.push(greenBars, direction > 0 ? 1 : 0)
    array.push(redBars,   direction < 0 ? 1 : 0)
    array.shift(greenBars)
    array.shift(redBars)
    
    greenBarCount := array.sum(greenBars)
    redBarCount   := array.sum(redBars)

plot(greenBarCount, 'greenBarCount', color.green)
plot(redBarCount,   'redBarCount',   color.red)
```

Comment: Added code for a shorter version.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! So, the way you code , it will look to the future to see if the current bar is in the first few bars of a series (the barsback number), which a code like "(close > close[1], 30) >= 16" (if I want 16 green bars in last 30 days) will not  do that, right?
And if I want to check the exactly number of green bar in the last 30 days, let's say 16 green bars greater or equal, so based your code, I just need to add something like "greenbarnumber = greenBarCount >=16" below the "redBarCount   := array.sum(redBars)" right? Thank you sir.